# tail -f does not follows files on WSL

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, tail

I have

```
F:\xampp-htdocs>wsl --list
Windows Subsystem für Linux-Distributionen:
Ubuntu-22.04 (Standard)
```

I cd into my logfiles on Window11 d:

```
/mnt/d/xampp-2024-15-01/apache/logs$
```

there i do

```
tail -f access.log
```

Tail just outputs the last lines but then does no longer follow the file.
Tryed this with different files within WSL and Windows11. no luck,

On an remote, external real Ubunt system "20.04.6 LTS (Focal Fossa)", tail -f works as expected.

What am i missing ?